# How to implement Excel formulas in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am programming a tool now by VBA and I have got a problem with writing a `IF` formula. I have two worksheets "site" and "overview", I would like to write an `IF` formula for the "site" worksheet range column L.

In the Excel formula bar it is the following formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK('Overview'!$Q$2:$Q$17), 'Site'L2:L17, 'Overview',Q2:Q17)
```

How should I write and implement this formula with a correct syntax in VBA. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate with VBA, or generate a string that will contain your formula in VBA?

Comment: The if function takes 3 arguments and I have counted 4 in your post. Could you share what is being accomplished by the formula

Answer (score 0):

For your formula, it is unclear which cells it is in. It cannot be in "Site" column L or "Overview" column Q, as your question suggests, because then you would have a circular reference. I'm going to assume it's in "Overview" column L.

Now to use the VBA `If` logic.

```
' Shorthand "With" to prefix "Sheets" with a dot "." means always reference this workbook
With ThisWorkbook

Dim vcell as Range
For Each vcell in .Sheets("Overview").Range("L2:L17")

    ' Check if column Q cell on same row is blank
    If .Sheets("Overview").Range("Q" & vcell.row).Text = "" then

        ' Value if vcell is blank
        vcell.Value = .Sheets("Site").Range("L" & vcell.row).value

    Else

        ' Value if vcell is not blank
        vcell.Value = .Sheets("Overview").Range("Q" & vcell.row).value            

    End If

End With
```

If you're used to writing formulae in Excel cells but not in VBA, you may find use for the WorksheetFunction ability of VBA: [MSDN Worksheet Function Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh211481(v=office.14).aspx). However, you're better off here using the native `If` logic for its added power and versatility, which is why there is no Worksheet Function for `If`.

Also take care copying cell formulae into the Worksheet Function sections of code. Your quotations around the sheet names would cause problems. I mention this because in VBA, the apostrophe `'` will start a comment, and so the code will be ignored!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an "Immediate If" for this type of thing but please make sure you fully understand the potential pitfalls of this syntax:

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3

Like so:

```
Set myRange = IIf([ISBLANK(Overview!$Q$2:$Q$17)], Sheets("site").Range(L2:L17), Sheets("Overview").Range("Q2:Q17"))
```